# How to take a polynomial form as input in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have  a polynomial of the form () = 0 + 1 + ⋯ +−1−1+.I want to take a0,a1...an  from user and n = length(a0,a1...an) example:
f = 3*x^2 - 4*x + 2.Help me please,thank you.

Comment: So you take the coefficients as input. What's the desired output?

Comment: `input`? Are you asking about how to take user input?

Answer (score 0):

```
a0=1;a1=3;a2=4;
A = [a0 a1 a2];

polyval(A,3)

ans = 
      22
```

using [`polyval`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/create-and-evaluate-polynomials.html). Note that the order of input arguments goes from highest to lowest, so in this example the polynomial is `x^2+3x+4`.

Since MATLAB is a numeric package, you'd generally want the numeric values of the polynomial evaluated at discrete values of `x`, and not a symbolic expression.